# Custom implementation of Play Framework's CookieSigner, CSRFTokenSigner etc

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm interested in having a play application which uses my own java implementations of `CookieSigner`, `CSRFTokenSigner` etc for play framework 2.5.

I'm using Google Guice and have attempted to inject my own but had no affirmative results.

Answer (score 1):

the mentioned "classes" or "Intefaces" or "trails" if you want to implement your own code, if you want to use the default, then inject `CSRFTokenSignerProvider`:

```
@Inject
private CSRFTokenSignerProvider csrfTokenSignerProvider;
```

Then you can use it like :

```
CSRFTokenSigner csrfTokenSigner = csrfTokenSignerProvider.get();
String token = csrfTokenSigner.generateToken();
String generatedSignedToken = csrfTokenSigner.generateSignedToken();
String signedToken = csrfTokenSigner.signToken(token);
String extractedSignedToken = csrfTokenSigner.extractSignedToken(signedToken);
boolean isMatch = csrfTokenSigner.compareSignedTokens(signedToken, generatedSignedToken);
```

If you want to implement code, you can refer to :

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/crypto

Comment: This is very close to what I ended up doing